# one UIImagePickerController for multiple UIImageViews in a single VC

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using a single UIImagePickerController to Pick 4 Images in the same viewController
i dont know hot to ask this question but if you look to the image down here you may understand what i mean

***for Example: Image(1) will be for Profile Photo And image(2) will be for ID ect***

and this is the result that I come up with
[when I chose the first image all the other images will show the same one so as the others.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zILuO.png)

```
class DriverAplication: UIViewController {

let driverPImg: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DriverPimg"))
        image.layer.cornerRadius = 75
        image.clipsToBounds = true
        image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        image.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return image
    }()

let passImg: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "passImg"))
        image.layer.cornerRadius = 75
        image.clipsToBounds = true
        image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        image.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return image
    }()
var profileSelectedImg: UIImage?
var passSelectedImg: UIImage?

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

view.addSubview(driverPImg)
view.addSubview(passImg)

let profileImgTapGestur = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(DriverAplication.selectProfileImage))
        driverPImg.addGestureRecognizer(profileImgTapGestur)
        
        let passImgTapGestur = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(DriverAplication.selectProfileImage))
        passImg.addGestureRecognizer(passImgTapGestur)

}

@objc func selectProfileImage(){
            let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light)
            generator.impactOccurred()
            let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
            pickerController.delegate = self
    //        PiActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
            pickerController.allowsEditing = true
            present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
        }
}

extension DriverAplication: UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            
            if let editedImg = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage {
                
                profileSelectedImg = editedImg.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
                driverPImg.image = editedImg
                
            } else if let originalImg = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                profileSelectedImg = originalImg.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
                driverPImg.image = originalImg
                
            }
        
          if let passEditedImg = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage {
                        
                        passSelectedImg = passEditedImg.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
                        passImg.image = passEditedImg
                        
                    } else if let passOriginalImg = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                        passSelectedImg = passOriginalImg.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
                        passImg.image = passOriginalImg
                        
                    }
 dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        
        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        //        self.PiActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
    
}
```

Comment: "picking all images will not be at the same time I mean the normal way one by one after finishing picking the first one you click on the other and pick another one ect" -- what does this mean?

Comment: pick one image then press on the second UIimage to pick another image, i just say that to ease the question to demonstrate

Comment: So you want to present a `UIImagePickerController` for picking the profile photo, and present another one for picking the ID photo? (2 separate pickers)

Comment: yes, but if I have to code another uiimagePickercontroller for every image that will frustrating

Comment: You could try the https://github.com/vhesener/Closures framework that extends several UIKit classes with closures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an `enum` to store the possible picker types (profile or ID picture).

```
enum PictureSelectionType {
    case profilePicture
    case idPicture
}
class DriverAplication: UIViewController {
    var pictureSelectionType = PictureSelectionType.profilePicture

    /// inside ViewDidLoad... 
    let profileImgTapGestur = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(DriverAplication.selectProfileImage))
    driverPImg.addGestureRecognizer(profileImgTapGestur)
        
    let passImgTapGestur = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(DriverAplication.selectIDImage))
    passImg.addGestureRecognizer(passImgTapGestur)

   
    @objc func selectProfileImage() {
        /// remember what the picker should return
        pictureSelectionType = .profilePicture
    
        let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light)
        generator.impactOccurred()

        let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        pickerController.delegate = self
        pickerController.allowsEditing = true
        present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
    }
    @objc func selectIDImage() {
        /// remember what the picker should return
        pictureSelectionType = .idPicture
    
        let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light)
        generator.impactOccurred()

        let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        pickerController.delegate = self
        pickerController.allowsEditing = true
        present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension DriverAplication: UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            
        var returnedImage: UIImage?
        if let editedImg = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage {
            returnedImage = editedImg
        } else if let originalImg = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            returnedImage = originalImg    
        }
        
        if let image = returnedImage { /// unwrap the image
 
            /// read what the selection type is
            if pictureSelectionType == .profilePicture {
                driverPImg.image = image
            } else { /// for ID picture
                passImg.image = image
            }
        }

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
        
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: if you know how can i check if all uiimageView (driverPImg, passImg) `!= nil` all of my uiimageView contains picked images

Comment: So you want to check if `driverPImg` and `passImg` contain images?

Comment: Like you said, just do `if driverPImg != nil { }` and `if passImg != nil { }`

Comment: `Comparing non-optional value of type 'UIImageView' to 'nil' always returns true`

Comment: so i tried `if driverPImg.image != nil && passImg.image != nil && carImg.image != nil{
                sendApplyBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.delevareColor
            }` even with && he's just cheking for the first item then he excute the code imediatly so if the `driverPImg.image != nil` my button will change color without checkin the rest of conditions

Comment: @aheze much easier to get the gesture view and cast it to UIImageView. Check the duplicate question post